# Where to find standard output or standard error from Java UDF in Hive

Tags: hive, cloudera-cdh

I am writing a Java UDF in Hive and for debugging I am printing some messages to standard output through LogFactory.getLog object. But I am wondering where I can see the messages. I am using CDH 5.4 and Hive 0.12

Comment: hi, did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Hive stores its logs in /tmp/currentuser location. When the Hive shell is invoked using the hive command at the Unix/Linux prompt, Hive displays the location of the log using the line Hive history file=location of the log before the Hive prompt is displayed. Example output is shown below:

```
[root@localhost root]# hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.10.0-cdh4.4.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties

Hive history file=/tmp/root/hive_job_log_46a27ee2-7ac1-43f5-a66b-20d6ea982421_849420221.txt
```

When you run a query from the Hive CLI, logs are stored for every query run (BeeLine and JDBC clients will not create these). You can manage these query log files as follows:

Set the location of the query log files (by default /tmp/user) and    reduce amount of logging by disabling progress based query logging by    specifying the following properties in the Hive Service Configuration    Safety Valve for hive-site.xml and Hive Client Configuration Safety    Valve for hive-site.xml :

```
 <property> 
          <name>hive.querylog.location</name> 
          <value>/Changed/Log/Directory</value> 
    </property> 
    <property> 
         <name>hive.querylog.enable.plan.progress</name> 
         <value>false</value> 
    </property>
```

- Save the changes to the configurations.
- Restart the Hive service and redeploy client configurations.